# Создание графического интерфейса в с++

Tags: c++

С помощью каких средств можно создать пользовательский интерфейс взамен стандартной командной строки в с++?

Comment: "голый" С++ средств работы с интерфейсом не предоставляет. Воспользуйтесь конкретными реализациями или библиотеками - QT, Embarcadero или даже чистый WinApi (если речь о Win)

Answer (score 1):

Для создания пользовательского интерфейса используются готовые библиотеки от разных производителей, надо только изучить их работу и классы. Для примера:

- Windows API - низкоуровневые интерфейсы windows
- MFC (Обертка над Window API)
- WTL (Облегченный MFC)
- Qt
- xWidgets
- многое другое: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Шаблон:Инструментарии_виджетов

Это не говоря о том, что можно еще пользоваться каким-нибудь DirectX и OpenGL. Попробуйте [Qt UI Framefork](http://qt-project.org/), очень часто натыкаюсь на то, как ее хвалят по сравнению с другими.

Comment: C++/CLI относится к С++ примерно как Java к JavaScript

Comment: @DreamChild, мне доводилось видеть только упоминания C++/CLI издали в обсуждениях типа "как создать на С++ проект WinForms". Так я о нем ничего не знаю и в скобках указал на всякий случай, что это не чистый С++.

Comment: @Alex Krass нет, это очень отличающийся от С++ язык на самом деле, поэтому боюсь, что WPF под С++ нет

Comment: @DreamChild, спасибо за пояснения, убрал из ответов упоминания о WinForms(C++/CLI) и WPF(C++/CLI), что бы не вводить никого в заблуждения.

Comment: Как ни странно, еще [tcl/tk](http://tcl.tk/about/).

--

Можно просто связать графический модуль с сишной программой через pty, хотя 
на самом деле там есть библиотека, которую можно использовать прямо из своей программы (в том же процессе).